# Align font size for tables with different number of columns

Tags: tables, floats, fontsize, textwidth

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I have a quite basic question. I create tables like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} }
            Test & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

However, I have a lot of tables and their number of columns differs. Accordingly, the font size changes automatically to my marginal settings (\resizebox{\textwidth}), i.e. the more columns the table has the smaller the font size. Is there a way to align the font size of **all** tables at once?

I know that I can decrease the font size manually by increasing the number within \extracolsep{5pt} to e.g.

```
\extracolsep{10pt}
```

However, I don't want to do this for every table and compare the results until they roughly coincide.

Thanks!

Comment: Without a complete example it is difficult to see but my first suggestion would be to get rid of the `\resizebox`. That should be used only as a last resort for desperate cases. Why should all tables have the same width? A table with ten columns will be likely broader than one with three; so?

Comment: These inconsistent  font sizes you observed are exactly the reason why you should not scale tables. If you want to make a table as wide as the textwidth, there are better options such as tabularx or tabular*. Which one to use depends on the table and its contents. There most likely is no solution that is applicable to all your tables.

Comment: never scale tables!

Answer (score 1):

Never scale tables, as you see, scaling just produces inconsistent font sizes.

Simply use

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
     \small
        \begin{tabular}{lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} }
            Test & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

or if `\small` is still too large `\footnotsize`.

Note that `\extracolsep` does nothing in `tabular` (it is used to give stretch space for `tabular*` to achieve the target width of the table). I also removed `[H]` which should be used *very* sparingly as it disables the float positioning algorithm (and specifying that the table may float is the sole purpose of the `table` environment).